# Unsigned Export of android app fails

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried everything: Project Clean, removed and reloaded all APIs in SDK Manager, checked project settings over and over, reading similar questions on SO and followed all recommendations. Restarted Eclipse, rebooted Mac, but it doesn't help. Project compiles ok and I can load it to device. But it won't export, not unsigned and not signed. The error message is weird. Console and Logcat are empty.
[image: Failed Export]

Comment: Remove the BIN directory, it will automatically be generated again. You could also try removing the GEN directory

Comment: doesn't help. I guess I have to delete Eclipse and reinstall it